# Connect MS Access to remote DB2 database without installing DB2 locally

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc, db2

I've found instructions on how to connect MS Access as a front-end to a DB2 database, but it appears that installing DB2 locally is a prerequisite (so that you have the DB2 ODBC driver). But I don't want to install locally. I want to connect to a remote DB2 database. I can't seem to figure out how I can get that driver installed without installing DB2. Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install the db2 client only.

Version 9.7 clients are [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg21385217).